# git clone error when running command 'gatsby new gatsby-site' - Command failed with exit code 1 (EPERM):

Tags: git, github, terminal, gatsby

I am trying to start a new gatsby project. When running the command 'gatsby new [my project name]' i get an error.

> Tomers-MBP:personal-projects tomermatmon$ gatsby new haifa-dev
>   info Creating new site from git: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git
>   xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

ERROR

> Command failed with exit code 1 (EPERM): git clone https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git haifa-dev --single-branch
>
> Error: Command failed with exit code 1 (EPERM): git clone https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby  -starter-default.git haifa-dev --single-branch
>
> - error.js:58 makeError
>     [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/lib/error.js:58:11
> - index.js:112 handlePromise
>     [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/index.js:112:26
> - next_tick.js:68 process._tickCallback
>     internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have the xcode cli tools installed on your mac. Sometimes it happens after a software update too.

Try running `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Can you explain how Xcode has anything to do with this?

Comment: The error message you posted mentions missing a reference to the command line tools. On MacOS, using many CLI tools, including node, often requires installing the command line tools. You can either do this through xcode itself, or by running the command mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, the command line tools were already installed. So I had to reset the path after the software update using the following command

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

I am using macOS Big Sur. Version - 11.1